# using raspberry pi usb to communicate with other device

Tags: java, linux, arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to using raspberry pi usb to communicate with other devices, however I encountered a problem when trying to open the port. The trace log from console is as follows:

```
11/24/14 13:56:48.641 + DLSUSBScale: Scale claim
11/24/14 13:56:48.641 + DLSUSBScale: Device claim
11/24/14 13:56:48.641 + DLSObjectFactory: createPort()
11/24/14 13:56:48.642 - DLSObjectFactory: createPort() - LinuxUSB
11/24/14 13:56:48.642 + DLSUsbJavax: openPort
11/24/14 13:56:48.642 + DLSUsbQuery: findDevice
11/24/14 13:56:48.642 = DLSUsbQuery: gettingUsbServices
11/24/14 13:56:48.643 *ERR* DLSUsbJavax: 0x80000001, Error while loading shared library libJavaxUsb.so: /home/pi/Desktop/dls/javaPOS/SupportJars/libJavaxUsb.so: /home/pi/Desktop/dls/JavaPOS/SupportJars/libJavaxUsb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
11/24/14 13:56:48.643 - DLSUsbJavax: openPort: false
11/24/14 13:56:48.643 *ERR* DLSUSBScale: Error opening port
11/24/14 13:56:48.643 *ERR* DLSScaleService: claim: 1110x80000004, Port open error
11/24/14 13:56:53.949 + DLSScaleService: getDataEventEnabled: false
11/24/14 13:56:53.949 - DLSScaleService: getDataEventEnabled
11/24/14 13:56:53.950 + DLSScaleService: getAsyncMode: false
11/24/14 13:56:53.950 - DLSScaleService: getAsyncMode
```

I do not know what is the problem and how can I figure it out.

And someone suggest me to load the USB-HID driver in Linux system (in my situation, it is raspbian). But I do not know where to download the USB-HID driver and how to load it.

By the way, I install Java on raspberry pi through:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: You are using a Java USB library whose native components are x86, while the raspberry pi is an ARM device. Get a USB library for ARM.

Comment: @that other guy, could you give me more detailed information about how to get a USB library for raspberry pi? thanks a lot!